# Plugin for drop outs for radio futz?

Tags: sound-design, foley

Doing some scenes with radio squelch/futz. Rather than cut out audio, is there of a plugin that would do this intermittently?

Answer (score 1):

I often use [Futzbox](http://www.mcdsp.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=317) for these types of things. But if it's just the intermittent dropouts you're after, a gate or expander can get you there. Start with a threshold that's roughly around your signal level, and dial in a fast attack and release. Then play around with the Hold parameter. To add more realism, you can then use that signal as the sidechain input to an inverted gate on some noise signal; that way you get static during the dropouts.

You could even experiment with using two gates on the voice; one for bigger dropouts that only occur every now and then, and another gate for smaller but more constant dropouts.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a device like that fairly easily in Max/MSP or the like. If you are starting with a voice recording I often end up going through, after processing the general sound of the voice itself, adding noise and creating drop-outs in the signal one by one. I have a bunch of radio noises that work for that purpose.  But I do wonder if anyone has any other methods that they use for this kind of thing

You could also do a more direct "analogue" method, for example playing back the audio into one walkie talkie and recording another walkie talkie.

As far as actual plugins...Izotope Vinyl does some of that sort of thing but with the goal of sounding like vinyl.  If you set up a gate that chops off bits of words, those gaps suggest signal is cutting out.

Let me know how it goes and what you end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these are of help:

http://www.modernbeats.com/modernbeats_vst_plugins.php (The Transistor plug-in)
http://www.avid.com/US/products/Cosmonaut-Voice
http://www.vst4free.com/free_vst.php?id=529&id_com2=4648&rep=1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I'm on PC so I can't use any MAC only plugs. I just thought of adding a midi gate to the track and triggering it with random midi notes to mute the track. I could then just copy more random notes over any part that needed the drop outs. I'll give it a try as well as some of these plugs mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do the tried-and-true EQ filtering and hard compression (with reverb and delay to place it in the environment), trie Audio Ease Speakerphone - same makers as Altiverb.  I'm not sure what you can do for dropouts, I'm guessing you can set certain parameters to do so.

But why not take more simple approach?  Edit out regions you want silent so that you can get the exact feel that your trying to get - this is how I do dropouts.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Audio Ease Speakerphone.